# What does "Contract can't be in try block" mean?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm using the 3.5 library for microsoft code contracts

```
public object RetrieveById(int Id)
{    
    //stuff happens...
    Contract.Ensures(newObject != null, "object must not be null");
    return newProject;
    //No error message if I move the Contract.Ensures to here
    //But it isn't asserting/throwing a contract exception here either           
}
```

I get the compiler message:
"Error 18 Contract section within try block in method 'Controller.RetrieveById(System.Int32)'

**UPDATE:**

I figured it out with your help:

- Move to top
- Check against Contract.Result

  Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() != null, "object must not be null ");

Comment: can you post your entire method contents. Also - `Contract.Ensures` must be the first line of code in any method. Code after your return statement will be unreachable.Thats why moving it there does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I just looked at the documentation for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412865.aspx

it says:

> This method call must be at the
>   beginning of a method or property,
>   before any other code.

So just leave the Ensures call at the top of the method and you should not get any problems.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple: the Contract class signals contract violations by throwing an exception.  Putting it in a try block defeats the purpose, you're liable to catch the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/codecontracts/thread/43f467f1-14b7-4e56-8030-50f842b7ba68

Your recent edit shows you have code above the `Contract.Ensures` statement. `Contract.Ensures` must come before any other code in your method, so:

```
public object RetrieveById(int Id)
{    
    //first line of method:
    Contract.Ensures(newObject != null, "object must not be null");

    //stuff happens...

    return newProject;        
}
```